# web-ui 2 way data binding

Tags: dart

I am new to dart.

I trying to build the [web-ui example](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-model-driven-view-with-dart.html) on Seth Ladd's blog. I have created a new application.

My html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Proefje</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Proefje.css"> 
  </head> 

  <body> 

    <h1>Hello MDV</h1> 
    <p>MDV is {{superlative}}</p> 
    <button id="change-it" on-click="changeIt()">Change</button> 

    <script type="application/dart" src="Proefje.dart"></script> 
    <script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

And the dart code like this:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:html'; 
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart'; // not sure about this line

String superlative; 
List<String> alternatives = const ['wicked cool', 'sweet', 'fantastic']; 
Random random; 

main() { 
  superlative = 'awesome'; 
  random = new Random(); 
  query('#change-it').text = 'Do Change'; 
} 

changeIt() => superlative = alternatives[random.nextInt(alternatives.length)];
```

And my pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name:  Proefje
description:  A sample application 

dependencies:   
  web_ui: any
```

When I run the app I see the query function changing the text in the button, but the `MDV is {{superlative}}` is left as is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile your html as described in the Setup section of Seth Ladd's blog.

> If you're new to Dart Web Components, you might want to read my [Your First Web Component](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-web-component-with-dart.html) with Dart post, or the [Dart Web Components article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/). Just like Dart Web Components, for MDV to work you need to get the web_components package, which contains the dwc compiler. The compiler is what converts the MVC and WC code into vanilla Dart and HTML.

Basically you can add a `build.dart` in your root directory with somthing like :

```dart
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/App.html']);
}
```

(see [Tools for Web UI](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/tools.html) )

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, I managed to get it working with your help and some help from the web-ui group. There is a issue with the editor and the version, but that will be solved in a few days.

Comment: lol, the new version just landed http://news.dartlang.org/2012/12/new-dart-editor-build-0282r15948.html

Comment: I also just launched a new Web UI codelab: http://news.dartlang.org/2012/12/new-dart-web-ui-codelab.html

Comment: Got it working now with web-ui 0.2.9 and editor build 0.2.8_r15948. Gonna port some AngularJS stuff to Dart, just to get me going :)